# How does Functional Completeness look like in the quantum world?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory

Can Post's theorem help to elucidate the nature of quantum logic or other non-classical logics? Quantum logic uses a different set of logical connectives than classical logic, which makes questions of functional completeness in quantum logic both challenging and potentially very interesting.